# Google App Engine - Quota Limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The documentation of Google App Engine Says:

> The number of times the application has been uploaded by a developer.
>   The current quota is 10,000 per day.
>       An application is limited to 10,000 uploaded files per version. Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes. Additionally,
>   if the total size of all files for all versions exceeds the initial
>   free 1 gigabyte, then there will be a $0.13 per GB per month charge.

I am planning to make an application which will have files uploaded by the user. I hope this 10,000 uploaded files refers to the files uploaded by the developer only and will not count for the user generated static content.

I am a bit confused about this. Clarification will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the 10,000 files limit is for the files uploaded by the developer as part of your application files.

In terms of files uploaded by your users, you must be aware that you cannot write to files in GAE but instead look at storing uploaded data in the Datastore, Blob or even other Cloud Storage options like Cloud SQL, Google Cloud Storage or even Google Drive.